# Can I change the update channel in Portable Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, automatic-update

I need some explanation on how to update a [Thunerbird Portable](http://portableapps.com/de/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable) installation to **beta** or **aurora**.

I tried to change the preferences in `about:config`, changing `update.channel` to aurora, but that had no effect.

Then I edited

```
ThunderbirdPortable3\App\thunderbird\defaults\pref\channel-prefs.js
```

and restarted Thunderbird. Then I got a message in the Help screen, saying that I am on update channel aurora, which seems fine. Still, the update downloaded Thunderbird 29 pre beta and tried to install but ended with the message that it couldn't be installed due to patch problems:

```
Das Update konnte nicht installiert werden (Patch-Anwendung fehlgeschlagen)
```

I tried this again with the channel "nightly" and got the same error. (On channel "beta" there seem to be no newer version than in the channel "release".)

How can I change my installation to channel aurora and update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update [Portable Thunderbird](http://portableapps.com/de/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable) to Earlybird

1. Close Thunderbird.
2. go to your Application directory:

   ```
   ThunderbirdPortable3\App
   ```
3. Rename the `thunderbird` folder to `thunderbird-channel-release`.
4. Download the latest release from  ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/nightly/latest-earlybird/
5. Unzip the `thunderbird-29.0a2.en-US.win32.installer.exe` (using, for example, 7zip).
6. Copy the `core` folder into  your `ThunderbirdPortable3\App` end rename it to `thunderbird`.
7. Start Thunderbird Portable.

You will now see that you have "Earlybird" and are on the aurora channel.

Comment: I am not sure, if this still works since TB 31. please report, if you had success still